# Parsing a YAML file using js-yaml

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, yaml

I am using js-yaml to parse and read the contents of a yaml file in node js, this is a typical key value pair yaml, 
 some of the keys in the Yaml have values in the format, example :

```
key : {{ val1 }} {{ val2 }}
```

The parsing is failing at such instances in the file. typically the error I get is:

> can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line X, column Y:\n

what is the best way to parse the Yaml which has some key/values in the above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{` is a special character in YAML which starts a flow sequence. You need to either quote the scalar that contains it:

```
key: "{{ val1 }} {{ val2 }}"
```

or use block scalars:

```
key: >-
  {{ val1 }} {{ val2 }}
```

Comment: Thanks @flyx it worked , another key I am having issue is where value is of format -name: {{ temp "name" . }}-config, it errors out saying -   message: 'can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 70, column 55:\n' +
    '     temp "name" . }}-config\n' +

Comment: @ptilloo If you have double quotes inside the string, you can use single quotes around it, e.g. `'{{ temp "name" . }}'`. The block scalar solution also works.

Comment: Thanks @flyx - it works - really appreciate the help